# Actively get microphone input

Tags: python

I am trying to actively get microphone input and console log it, for the start.

I have tried using SpeechRecognition like this

```
import speech_recognition as sr

while True:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(text)
```

But it waits for the sound to stop, then prints the words.
Is it possible to detect each word and output it when I say it?